# Implement textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: for subclass of UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

The `tableviewcells` are put in a view controller. It is okay for me to set different properties of the `UITextField`. However, I cannot find a way to implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` successfully.

How should I do? Thanks.

1. `myTextField` - a subclass of `UITextField`, conformed to `<UITextFieldDelegate>`
2. `myTableViewCell` - a subclass of UITableViewCell
   In this subclass, a myTextField property is declared and is connected to the nib layout.
3. `myViewController` - a subclass of `UIViewController`, conformed to `<UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`. A nib file is created with a Table View, the Table View is connected to a table view property. An ivar of `myTableViewCell` is also declared, named myCell.

In `viewDidLoad` of `myViewController`, followings are invoked:
    [[myCell myTextField] setDelegate:self];
    [myTableView setDelegate:self];
    [myTableView setDataSource:self];

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is also implemented in `myViewController`. But by breakpoint, it is found not implemented at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the `textField` delegate is pointing to the `viewcontroller` class, rit ?
I think your problem is in identifying which textField is calling that delegate method.

In that case 1 solution will be to point the `textField.delegate` to the `UITableViewCell`
or else if u need to handle that in the controller,
set the tag for each of the `textField` in the method cellForRowAtIndexpath: (based on `indexPath.row`)
and in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` compare with `[textField Tag]`

Comment: I've setDelegate pointing to the viewcontroller. But the method isn't implemented at all (checked by breakpoint). Please read my question again. I've updated with more detail description of my codes.

Comment: Are your cells static? or are you allocating the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath? did you try setting the textfield delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath? I think your textField is nil when you are setting the delegate

Comment: Finally, the problem is solved by that I set textfield delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of viewDidLoad. Thanks so much!!